# sql nested sum query

Tags: sql

I have a single table that I need to create three sum's based off the month on an invoice.

The sums are calculated using the first three letters of an 'invoice_number' field, Then adding all the 'Invoice_Amount' for that specific invoice type.

Example of data
Invoice_Number - MSP-1111
Invoice Amount - $2100.00

I want to calculate this based off months so it formats as example

```
Year | Month | Total MSP Invoices| Total PS Invoices | Total App Invoice
```

I am able to get the months, however the total is the same for all months, not specific to that month.  Below is the query I am using.

I want to display the last 12 months.

```
select year(date_invoice) as Year, 
    Case month(date_invoice)
        When 1 Then 'Jan'
        When 2 Then 'Feb'
        When 3 Then 'March'
        When 4 Then 'April'
        When 5 Then 'May'
        When 6 Then 'June'
        When 7 Then 'July'
        When 8 Then 'Aug'
        When 9 Then 'Sept'
        When 10 Then 'Oct'
        When 11 Then 'Nov'
        When 12 then 'Dec' 
    End 
as Month,
(Select sum(invoice_amount) from invoices where Invoice_number like 'MSP%') as 'MSP',
(Select sum(invoice_amount) from invoices where Invoice_number like 'PS%') as'PS',
(Select sum(invoice_amount) from invoices where Invoice_number like 'APP%') as 'App'
from invoices
Where convert(nvarchar(50), date_invoice,100) > DATEADD(month, -12,  getdate())
Group by year(date_invoice), month(date_invoice)
Order by year(date_invoice), month(date_invoice)
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the case statement in the group by which would group it right

```
 select year(date_invoice) as Year, 
Case month(date_invoice)
    When 1 Then 'Jan'
    When 2 Then 'Feb'
    When 3 Then 'March'
    When 4 Then 'April'
    When 5 Then 'May'
    When 6 Then 'June'
    When 7 Then 'July'
    When 8 Then 'Aug'
    When 9 Then 'Sept'
    When 10 Then 'Oct'
    When 11 Then 'Nov'
    When 12 then 'Dec' 
End 
as Month,
 (Select sum(invoice_amount) from invoices where Invoice_number like 'MSP%') as 'MSP',
 (Select sum(invoice_amount) from invoices where Invoice_number like 'PS%') as'PS',
 (Select sum(invoice_amount) from invoices where Invoice_number like 'APP%') as 'App'
 from invoices
 Where convert(nvarchar(50), date_invoice,100) > DATEADD(month, -12,  getdate())
 Group by year(date_invoice),  Case month(date_invoice)
    When 1 Then 'Jan'
    When 2 Then 'Feb'
    When 3 Then 'March'
    When 4 Then 'April'
    When 5 Then 'May'
    When 6 Then 'June'
    When 7 Then 'July'
    When 8 Then 'Aug'
    When 9 Then 'Sept'
    When 10 Then 'Oct'
    When 11 Then 'Nov'
    When 12 then 'Dec' 
End 
Order by year(date_invoice), month(date_invoice)
```

Comment: Why not use a cte or derived table to save lots of typing?

Comment: No reason you couldn't. Just my approach

Comment: When I try this approach I get the following,  "invoices.Date_Invoice" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Answer (score 0):

Have a derived table where you put the `CASE` expression to get month names.

Use `CASE` expressions to do conditional `SUM`'s.

```
select year, month,
       sum(case when Invoice_number like 'MSP%' then invoice_amount end) as 'MSP',
       sum(case when Invoice_number like 'PS%' then invoice_amount end) as 'PS',
       sum(case when Invoice_number like 'APP%' then invoice_amount end) as 'APP'
from
(
select date_invoice,
       Invoice_number
       year(date_invoice) as Year, 
       case month(date_invoice)
         When 1 Then 'Jan'
         When 2 Then 'Feb'
         When 3 Then 'March'
         When 4 Then 'April'
         When 5 Then 'May'
         When 6 Then 'June'
         When 7 Then 'July'
         When 8 Then 'Aug'
         When 9 Then 'Sept'
         When 10 Then 'Oct'
         When 11 Then 'Nov'
         When 12 then 'Dec' 
       End as Month,
       invoice_amount
from invoices
where convert(nvarchar(50), date_invoice,100) > DATEADD(month, -12,  getdate())
) as dt
Group by year, month
Order by year, month
```

Comment: You should put the `where` inside the derived table, so can use the date index (I assume should be one for `date`) and dont bring all the invoice

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, Good point. But I'll not edit right now - since if index can be used or not when a derived table is involved depends on the dbms used - and no dbms is tagged here. (Maybe later, when we know which dbms it is.) BTW, doesn't that convert ruin index usage for at least some products?

Comment: Even if not index you are doing some "expensive" calculations `year(), month() case` for all the rows instead of just the last 12 months.

Comment: Well, that too depends on the dbms optimizer. But since it's Friday and the weekend soon is here I'll move the condition into the derived table sub-query.

Comment: yes, convert ruin the index, but in the inner select you can use `date_invoice` so dont know why convert that to nvarchar. Or maybe I understanding the convert wrong.

Comment: This got what I needed, now people just have to invoice correctly for it to be accurate lol.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

select year, month,
       sum(case when Invoice_number like 'MSP%' then invoice_amount end) as 'MSP',
       sum(case when Invoice_number like 'PS%' then invoice_amount end) as 'PS',
       sum(case when Invoice_number like 'APP%' then invoice_amount end) as 'APP'
from
(
select date_invoice,
       Invoice_number
       year(date_invoice) as Year, 
       case month(date_invoice)
         When 1 Then 'Jan'
         When 2 Then 'Feb'
         When 3 Then 'March'
         When 4 Then 'April'
         When 5 Then 'May'
         When 6 Then 'June'
         When 7 Then 'July'
         When 8 Then 'Aug'
         When 9 Then 'Sept'
         When 10 Then 'Oct'
         When 11 Then 'Nov'
         When 12 then 'Dec' 
       End as Month,
       invoice_amount
from invoices
where convert(nvarchar(50), date_invoice,100) > DATEADD(month, -12,  getdate())
) as dt
Group by year, month
Order by year, month